# What is Dlib Module Error in python-OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

In python, i have written the below code.

```
import dlib
import cv2
import numpy as np

ImportError: Module use of python35.dll conflicts with this version of 
Python.
```

Please help with the mismatched dll file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Make sure there is no mismatch with python version with the dll file .@Amit Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should install everything in a virtual environment. Please follow the below steps and you should be able to get going.

1. Install Anaconda [Download](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows)
2. Create Virtual Environment - `conda create --name opencv-env python=3.7`
3. Activate Environment - `acitivate opencv-env`
4. Install required packages

   `pip install numpy scipy matplotlib scikit-learn jupyter
   pip install opencv-contrib-python cmake
   pip install dlib`

For a more detailed instructions look at [this tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-and-dlib-on-windows-python-only/)